# Should I use separate models for Users and Profiles in Ruby on Rails 3 for the associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, model-associations

At first I had in mind just a `User` model for the authentication on my application but then i Decided to give this users a profile so I created the `Profile` model, now:

`User`
  `has_one :profile`

and

`Profile`
  `belongs_to :user`

Is this correct or should I just keep one model, let's say `User`, and keep there all the fields corresponding to profile and delete the `Profile` model?

Thanks.

== Update

This are the attributes of `User` and `Profile` Models.

`User`

- username
- password

`Profile`

- name
- last_name
- email
- website
- picture
- about

Comment: Depends on what do you have in each models. Can you show us the attributes of each ?

Comment: There's no "should" in this case, really--I tend to start small, and extract logical chunks when necessary.

Comment: @damienbrz I just updated the question with the attributes, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the user model with the authentication attribute and the profile with the specific and personal information is alright.

There is not "right" way.

I think this one is ok.